# How do I profile a WCF service?

Tags: wcf, performance, profiling

I am in the process of performance testing the entire system. I used SlimTune on some Winform Applications in order to identify bottlenecks and I like it, it was very simple to use and understand.

Now I want to do the same over some WCF services (all self hosted).
What Tools should I use? (free tools please)
Is there any way to use SlimTune for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get started with WCF Performance profiling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936853/how-to-get-started-with-wcf-performance-profiling)

Answer (score 0):

The following thread asks the same question and has some good advice.

[How to get started with WCF Performance profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936853/how-to-get-started-with-wcf-performance-profiling)