# VS Profiling of ASP.net with WCF misses all WCF calls

Tags: asp.net, wcf, visual-studio, azure, profiling

Running instrumented profiling against our WCF services in our ASP.net website it is as if all WCF calls never took place, though it is easy to verify that they did. But they appear to be invisible to the profiler. This is true running locally as well as profiling against the website running on azure.

Sampled profiling picks up the WCF calls, but instrumented profiling is what we really need. What could be causing instrumented profiling to simply miss all these WCF calls? Most importantly, how can we make the WCF calls visible in our instrumented profiling, particularly on azure?

Comment: what version of Visual Studio?

Comment: Visual studio 2012. Same results for ultimate and pro.

Comment: have you read this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936853/how-to-get-started-with-wcf-performance-profiling